# ASP.Net Core 3.0 Dependency Injection ignoring Factory Methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I recently migrated to ASP.NET Core 3.0 and facing the DI issue while startups... they were working fine for ASP.NET Core 2.2. If I use the old WebHostBuilder in ASP.NET CORE 3.0 then I do not see the issues. Not sure is the issues are specific to new HostBuilder in Program.cs or DI has changed in 3.0.

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
}
```

I have the **UniqueRowKeyUserStore** class as below. The constructor takes 4 interfaces.

```
public class UniqueRowKeyUserStore : UserStore<UniqueRowKeyUser>
{
    public UniqueRowKeyUserStore(IStoreMetadata storeMetadata, ILookupNormalizer dataNormalizer, IDataProtector dataProtector, ILookupSplitter<StorablePartitionRowKeys> defaultMerger) : base(storeMetadata, dataNormalizer, dataProtector, defaultMerger)
        {        }
}
```

In configure services, I register a scoped service with a factory function

```
services.AddScoped<UniqueRowKeyUserStore>(StartupService.NewUserStore);
```

**StartupService.NewUserStore** is a factory method that creates an instance of UniqueRowKeyUserStore

```
public static UniqueRowKeyUserStore NewUserStore(IServiceProvider arg)
{
return new UniqueRowKeyUserStore(new DefaultMetadata(), new DefaultNormalizer(), new DefaultProtecttor(), new DefaultSplitter());
}
```

As you can see that I am using the Factory method to create the instance so the expectation is **that DI should not complain about IStoreMetadata or other interfaces which are expected in constructor.**

But I get the error during startup, **it does look like the DI in asp.net core 3.0 is ignoring the factory method** ?

**InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IStoreMetadata' while attempting to activate 'UniqueRowKeyUserStore'.**

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in ASP.NET Core 3.0

Comment: Have you tried doing the factory manually to make sure? `services.AddScoped<UniqueRowKeyUserStore>(sp => return new UniqueRowKeyUserStore(...));`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Firstly, my Identity's `UserStore` does not have such constructor, and do not have `IStoreMetadata` or `ILookupSplitter`, so I am not sure which one you are using. Secondly, if it is all correct, VS should tell you that you can remove `<UniqueRowKeyUserStore>` at the AddScoped, right?

Comment: @Nkosi yes I tried the factory manually as suggested by you but the same issue...

Comment: Then there is some other registration overriding the one shown.I suggest  you check the service collection while debugging to make sure

Comment: @LukeVo  The issue is reproducible even if you have 1 interface in the constructor. I believe this is pretty standard to have in DI. These interfaces are needed and it worked in asp.net core 2.2. Regarding the VS telling about simplifying will not change anything as the same method will implicitly reference the service type from factory method... the VS will just simplify the code.

Comment: @Nkosi  I have the services.AddIdentity<UniqueRowKeyUser, UserRole>().AddUserStore<UniqueRowKeyUserStore>()   but why should this overlap as I am registering the custom UserStore and then telling the DI how to construct it using factory method... how did this worked in 2.2 then ?

Comment: `.AddUserStore<UniqueRowKeyUserStore>()` is what is causing the problem right there.

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** doing? The limited snippets did not provide the bigger picture.

Comment: @Nkosi thanks but your comments helped me fix the issue... see my answer below... let me know if you want me to change anything I will be happy to update if someone else face the same issue...

Comment: @Ameya I found the source code to see why It caused your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.AddUserStore<UniqueRowKeyUserStore>()` is what is causing the problem right there.

```
/// <summary>
/// Adds an <see cref="IUserStore{TUser}"/> for the <see cref="UserType"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TStore">The user store type.</typeparam>
/// <returns>The current <see cref="IdentityBuilder"/> instance.</returns>
public virtual IdentityBuilder AddUserStore<TStore>() where TStore : class
    => AddScoped(typeof(IUserStore<>).MakeGenericType(UserType), typeof(TStore));
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityBuilder.cs#L108)

Note how it is added as `IUserStore<>`

So you are correct that it is not calling your registration of your implementation. It is looking for the abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen if something else injects that same class later (for example, `AddIdentity`).

I cannot reproduce the problem you are describing and do not have the same classes in my Identity package (I guess you are using an extended one?), so I have to create my own:

```
        services.AddScoped<MyUserStore>(sp => new MyUserStore(new DefaultComponent2()));
        services.AddScoped<MyUserStore>(sp => new MyUserStore(new DefaultComponent()));
        services.AddScoped<MyUserStore>();
```

If I have only the first 2 lines, whenever I request `MyUserStore`, I get `DefaultComponent()`. However, if I add the 3rd line (and I never registered any `IComponent`), I get the same error message as you described.

Comment: ok, thanks for the pointer... yes i am using the extended user stores...  let me check if there is something else that injects... but surprising the exact same code worked in core 2.2 i just migrated to 3.0 and startup stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @LukeVo and @Nkosi... the comments helped me debug the issue. I have no idea why the exact same code worked in asp.net core 2.2 but the DI in asp.net core 3.0 will complain about duplicate registration for service and ignore the factory method.

I have custom UserStore and UserRoleStore and I use Identity to register as below... I had to remove the **.AddUserStore()** and **.AddUserRoleStore()** as I am going to register my cutomer stores with factory method so that I can pass additional data (interfaces IStoreMetaData, ILookupNormalizer etc...)

```
services.AddIdentity<UniqueRowKeyUser, UserRole>()
                        .AddRoles<UserRole>()
                        .AddUserManager<UserManager<UniqueRowKeyUser>>()
                        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<UserRole>>()
                        .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<UniqueRowKeyUser>>()
                        .AddErrorDescriber<TranslatedIdentityErrorDescriptor>()
                        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Now for registering the Factory method, **the below code will not work** as DI is not able to map to the store types registered by AddIdentity as explained above.

```
services.AddScoped<UniqueRowKeyUserStore>(StartupService.NewUserStore);
services.AddScoped<UserRoleStore>(StartupService.NewUserRoleStore);
```

**So I had to change service registration and use IUserStore and IRoleStore** with my factory methods and now its working...

```
 services.AddScoped<IUserStore<UniqueRowKeyUser>, UniqueRowKeyUserStore>(StartupService.NewUserStore);
 services.AddScoped<IRoleStore<UserRole>, UserRoleStore>(StartupService.NewUserRoleStore);
```